# Need to allow column order (alphabetical) changes in Excel when refreshing data link to MS Access query

Tags: excel, ms-access

I need to daily refresh a MS Excel spreadsheet that connects to a MS Access query however the sorting of the columns in Excel over time do not match the sorting order of the columns in Access (which I need to happen).
The MS Access query's columns (formatted as YYYY-MM-DD and sorted in alphabetical order) will change daily however when the excel file is refreshed the columns do not dynamically change order to reflect MS Access query.  The Excel columns remain in their order from when the linkage to the MS Access query was originally created and any future-created columns are only added to the right of the farthest-right, original column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, please indicate which of these situations better describe your issue:

Is your issue related to differences in the order of rows within each column or the left-to-right sorting of columns?  If it is the left-to-right order of your problem, could you add some detail on how Excel is linked to Access?

There are differences in the way MS Access alphabetically sorts *rows* within each column versus the way Excel handles alphabetical sorting rows within each column.  For instance, Excel will sort "A" ahead of "a".  Access General-legacy collation will do this the other way around.  This gets trickier if Access is just the front-end for another database.  But it sounds like you have an issue with the left-to-right alphabetical sequence of columns.